# How can I improve how this object is instantiated?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider this "design" (implementation details left out):

```
struct service {};

struct sub {
  sub(service&) {}
  service& s_;
};

struct sub_a: sub {
  sub_a(service&) {}
};

struct sub_b: sub {
  sub_b(service&) {}
};

struct top {
  service svc_;
  sub_ptr sub_;
};
```

Basically, my `top` object holds `sub_ptr`, but the instance held by this pointer requires access to `svc_` in order to be instantiated, which is also in `top`. However, I want a user of `top` to be able to choose the type of `sub` (here `sub_a` or `sub_b`), without giving access to `svc_`.

My solution so far is to have my constructor of `top` like this:

```
template <typename SubType>
top(std::unique_ptr<SubType>): sub_(new SubType(svc_)) {}
```

Here is the usage:

```
auto t = top(std::unique_ptr<sub_b>());
```

But I don't feel like this solution is elegant. I could write functions (eg. `make_top_sub_b()`) to hide the details, but I was wondering how I could avoid giving a dummy pointer to my constructor? Making `top` a templated class is not an option.

Any idea how I could improve this? Thanks,

Comment: As far as I can see this looks like a problem solved by a Factory pattern. A simple version of the Factory pattern is to delegate the construction of your type to a function as you suggest with `make_top_sub_b`. I'd say your pretty much on the right track there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Liskov substitution principle would hear suggest that **users** of `sub_ptr` would not need to be aware of which implementation it held.

As `sub_ptr` is wrapped within `top`, you can say that `top` is a user.

The construction of the `sub` needs to be done via its factory and the `service` it references must have a lifetime that is longer than that of the class that holds the reference.

In your case the lifetime of the service object appears to be in `top` which means the `sub` must have a shorter lifetime.

You could have a `sub_factory` class that is abstract and creates one from a service.

e.g.

```
struct sub_factory
{
   virtual sub* create( service_ & ) const = 0;
};


struct sub_a_factory : sub_factory 
{ 
       // detail, creates sub_a
};

struct sub_b_factory : sub_factory
{
     // detail, creates sub_b
};

top::top( sub_factory const & fact ) :
      sub_( fact.create( svc_ ) )
{
}

sub_factory_a afact;
sub_Factory_b bfact;
top ta(  afact );
top tb( bfact );
```

Note that you can use the initialiser list here as svc_ appears above sub_ in your class so gets initialised first.

Comment: That's not what LSP is about. It's about the various subclasses of `sub` being all usable as a `sub`. The user can know which one it creates just fine. (In the same vein, do you want to argue your factory design does not go against the same interpretation of LSP you used? Because the user of the factory needs to know which factory it creates)

Comment: The creator can know which one is created, the user should not need to know which is being used. Yes, it should be possible to substitute any of them in.